# Using jQuery to find certain text, then add class onto the following UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to add a class onto a UL depending on the text used in the navigation.

For example.

```
   <li>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
   </li>
```

I want to add a class onto the ul depending on the text inside the a tag, to find the text I just use the a:contains method

```
$('#nav > li > a:contains("text")')
```

After that I draw a blank on how to add a class onto the ul that follows, I thought the .next might work but it turns out it doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The text match is case-sensitive...`text` and `Text` don't match so the `<a>` is never found. Otherwise `next` or one of the answers below would work

Comment: As Clive said, it never finds string that you're looking for, 'cause it's a different string. next() works just fine after you take that into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, like:

```
$('#nav > li > a:contains("Text") + ul')
```

? If the `<ul>` could be anywhere after that, use:

```
$('#nav > li > a:contains("Text") ~ ul')
```

. Edit: Also, `Text`'s casing is wrong. `:contains` is case-sensitive (as others have pointed out now).

Answer (score 5):

This should work. Remember contains is case sensitive:

```
$('#nav > li > a:contains("Text")').next().addClass('testClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly your next doesn't go nowhere because you did not select an jquery object. do something like

```
$('#nav > li > a').each(function(){
if(yourCondition){
$(this).next('ul').addClass('yourClass');
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't selecting the `a` element to begin with.

The case should match:

```
$('#nav > li > a:contains("Text")')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### P.S: Matching "text" with "Text" isn't getting any match(s).

Make it ..

`$('#nav > li > a:contains("Text")').next('ul').addClass('my-new-class');`

.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the casing of the text should be the same in order to get a positive result on the selection.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            ul.square {list-style-type:square; font-size:x-large;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#nav li a:contains("Text")').siblings('ul').addClass("square");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li>some item</li>
            <li>another item <a href="#">uninteresting link</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>sublist item</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Special List</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: only if you had read the [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), you would not have labored hard to include code in the answer :-)